# Why load environment variable main function golang

Tags: mysql, go, environment-variables

While making a Golang application

Regarding the reading method of Mysql, it is better to read the environment variable with the main function and pass it to the argument.

The reason causes environment variables are a kind of global variable situation where you don't know why the DB package connects to a host called XXX when viewed from outside a module during testing. I received an explanation that a suspicion was born that a fixed value might be written

this current code

```
mysql.go

func Init() *gorm.DB {
    path := strings.Join([]string{os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER"), ":", os.Getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"), "@tcp(", os.Getenv("DB_HOST"), ":", os.Getenv("DB_PORT"), ")/", os.Getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE"), "?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"}, "")

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = db.DB().Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    DB = db

    return DB
}
```

```
main.go

func main {

    db := mysql.Init()
    defer db.Close()

}
```

I would be happy if you could tell me if you know the best way to do that.

Thank you

Comment: I would use a config file for this purpose. There you add your initialization strings and read them in the init phase of your program.

Comment: To improve testability, it's better to interface with the calling context (command-line args, environment variables, etc) in `main` and pass those values to functions that use them. That way tests can call those same functions with test values as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would have a separate structure that holds all the configuration values. Then, you can have functions that populate the config structure from various sources (env variables, file, etc.)

Additionally, you could use `fmt.Sprintf` to improve the path building.

Here is a rough example how it might look.

```golang
func Init() *gorm.DB {
    cfg := LoadConfigFromEnvironment()
    path := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
        cfg.DBUser,
        cfg.DBPassword,
        cfg.DBHost,
        cfg.DBPort,
        cfg.DBName,
    )

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = db.DB().Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

**Note** also how I have removed the `DB = db` assignment. Not sure what that was about, but you should not be assigning to a global variable from that function.

As others have mentioned, ideally, you should separate configuration loading from initialization, so the definition of `Init` would better look as follows.

```golang
func Init(cfg Config) *gorm.DB {
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks!!

I understand the importance of reading environment variables with the main function

But on the other hand, I don't know how to load it.
Can you give me some more examples?

Comment: I was able to solve it by referring to your advice.
Thank you